# How to avoid space deletion in paragraphs while removing special characters in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

So, I tried to remove special character from dataset .csv file using python code but it removes the special character as well as word spacing from paragraphs. To avoid deletion of spaces what is the best solution ?.

```
    df['text'] = df['text'].str.replace('\W', '', regex=True)
    print(df)
```

Comment: Because `\W` matches everything that is not letter, number, or underscore.  That includes whitespace.

Comment: Then what's the right code ?

Comment: The answer below is right.  `[^\w\s]`.

Answer (score 2):

`\W` matches anything that isn't a *word character*, which is [defined as](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Cheatsheet)

> alphanumeric character from the basic Latin alphabet, including the underscore. Equivalent to [A-Za-z0-9_].

We also have `\w` (lowercase w) which matches *only* word characters.

You want to replace anything that's *not* a *word character* or a space, so create a character class that matches only word characters and spaces, and negate it:

```
df['text'] = df['text'].str.replace(r'[^\w\s]', '', regex=True)
```

Comment: it removes all the characters and words under text column ....

Comment: Did you copy that `^` when you typed it?  That's the key, because it inverts the pattern.